# Using GPUImageRGBFilter

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, gpuimage

I've trying to use the GPUImageRGBFilter but without success. I want to change each channel value, for instance:

```
Red: 0.2
Green: 0.4
Blue: 0.3
```

How can I do this? Can anyone tell me how to use GPUImageRGBFilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you want to do is multiply the values of each color channel by the values in your post, the solution should be pretty simple;

```
GPUImageRGBFilter *rgbFilter = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];
[rgbFilter setRed:.2];
[rgbFilter setGreen:.4];
[rgbFilter setBlue:.3];
```

Then use `addTarget:` and `processImage` as the [documentation](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#readme) instructs.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are Given there in GPUImageRGBFilter Class please check for

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) CGFloat red;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) CGFloat green;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) CGFloat blue;